# how to merge rows ina csv file if if the first column is same in bash

Tags: awk, control-m

I have written a program to find the open ports of a given IP.
since the print function is in a loop my output format is like this:

```
IP1,22
IP1,23
IP1,24
IP2,25
IP2,26
IP3,27
IP3,30
IP3,45
```

How do I get it in this format:

```
IP1,22,23,24
IP2,25,26
IP3,27,30,45
```

EDIT:
this is what I have done so far

```
awk'{a[$1]=(a[$1])? a[$1]r : r }
```

but I dont know how to progress forward from here.

Comment: my main code is in python and I am making changes to the python code to print the output on this format.However on the output files that I already have i want to just convert them into that format so I dont have to run the scan again

Comment: @AnujKulkarni, it is always advised to add your effort in your post as we all are here to learn, kindly do so and let us know.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 ok I have an incomplete code as I am not very fluent with awk i will edit my question with my efforts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kindly always do add your efforts in your question in code tags. If you are not worried for order of output then try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {a[$1]=($1 in a ? a[$1] OFS : "") $2} END{for(i in a){print i,a[i]}}'  Input_file
```

In case you need to get output in same order in which 1st field of Input_file is coming then try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
!b[$1]++{
  c[++count]=$1
}
{
  a[$1]=($1 in a ? a[$1] OFS : "") $2
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print c[i],a[c[i]]
  }
}'  Input_file
```

Since later OP found out control-m characters were found in Input_file(s) too so adding following:

```
tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

Comment: this prints the output as ip1,port1\n,port2\n,port3\n rather than printing it in one row

Comment: @AnujKulkarni, could you please check if your Input_file have control M by doing `cat -v Input_file` if yes then removbe them by doing `tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file`.

Comment: thanks.My input file had control M.corrected it with your given code. Could you please shed some light upon why the control M character is introduced? thanks

Comment: @AnujKulkarni, when we copy something from windows to unix then they appear usually.

Answer (score 2):

Another awk..

```
$ cat anuj.txt
IP1,22
IP1,23
IP1,24
IP2,25
IP2,26
IP3,27
IP3,30
IP3,45
$ awk -F, ' { c=$1; if(c!=p) { printf("\n%s,%d",$1,$2)} else { printf(",%d",$2) } p=c } END { print ""} ' anuj.txt

IP1,22,23,24
IP2,25,26
IP3,27,30,45
$
```

There is an empty line in the above solution. To get rid of it, you can use below

```
$ awk -F, ' { c=$1; if(c!=p) { printf("%s%s,%d",sep,$1,$2)} else { printf(",%d",$2) } p=c;sep="\n" } END { print ""} ' anuj.txt
IP1,22,23,24
IP2,25,26
IP3,27,30,45
$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sort anuj.txt | cut -d, -f1 | sort -u  | while read line; do echo $line,$(grep $line anuj.txt | cut -d, -f2 | paste -sd, -); done
```

Assumptions:
Your file is comma separated and has the same format you show above.

Explanation (FWIW):
First find the unique IP identifiers, then grep for that string in the file, for each line found get the second field and concatenate them.